# Keeping track of AsyncTask status to update ListView items

Tags: android, download, android-asynctask

I have a `ListView` that shows a bunch of downloadable objects. When the user clicks a list item, the item gets downloaded through an `AsyncTask`, and a notification is also made showing the download progress. I also want the progress to show inside the ListView item.

I want behave more or less like Google Drive when you make an item available offline.

My problem: considering situations where the the app is closed before the download is complete, I can't think of a robust way of 'storing' the download status that can be retrieved in `getView()`.

Should `onProgressUpdate()` best store the download progress in the database, a variable inside the activity or modify the ListView child item directly?

**EDIT**

For anyone interested, I used a service that sends out a broadcast when the download status changes:

Activity:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mDataSetChangedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(downloadDetailFragment!=null){
            downloadDetailFragment.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mDataSetChangedReceiver,
      new IntentFilter(DownloadService.DOWNLOAD_STATUS_CHANGED));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
```

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mDataSetChangedReceiver);
    }

AsyncTask:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(DownloadService.DOWNLOAD_STATUS_CHANGED);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), which it looks you might be doing anyway if you have a notification tracking the download. If you can track the progress in your `Service` and send that info to the `ListView` also, you could show the `ProgressBar` in both easily.

Using a `Service` would also let you store the downloaded information using `SharedPreferences` so you could access it later if the app is closed. Kinda conceptual but I hope this helps.

Comment: Nice, I'll go try it out. Didn't think of `SharedPreferences` before.

Comment: Should I use a `BroadcastReceiver` in the ListView listening to updates from the service? The service can't hold a reference to the `ListView`...

Comment: I would just have the service write straight to the `SharedPreferences`. I might be wrong, but there doesn't seem to be a need for wiring up a `BroadcastReceiver` unless you're doing some kind of background sync when the user isn't interacting.

Comment: Yeah, but the ListView isn't polling SharedPreferences, so it needs to be notified when something changes.

Comment: You could fire off the `Service` and have it write to both a global variable and `SharedPreferences`. Use the global variable to populate your `ListView`. On app startup, you can then grab the data from `SharedPreferences` to populate the initial `ListView` too.